# transmission "Permission denied" error

Tags: server, permissions, bittorrent, transmission

I installed web version of transmission on my Ubuntu Server 14.10

To make it work with my home folder I did this:

> cd /home/nat/Downloads
>
> mkdir transmission
>
> sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission nat
>
> sudo chgrp -R debian-transmission /home/nat/Downloads/transmission
>
> sudo chmod -R 775 /home/nat/Downloads/transmission

Then I changed unmask to "2" in /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json

Everything worked well but I decided to do all this steps with my HDD (it is Ext4) that mounted at /media/nat/1

> cd /media/nat/1
>
> mkdir transmission
>
> sudo chgrp -R debian-transmission /media/nat/1/transmission
>
> sudo chmod -R 775 /media/nat/1/transmission

But it doesn't work.

When I try to load a torrent it says:

Error: Permission denied (/media/nat/1/transmission/)

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.

> nat@nat:/media/nat/1/transmission$ ls -l
>
> total 12 drwxrwxr-x 2 nat
>
> debian-transmission 4096 марта 28 06:06 completed drwxrwxr-x 2 nat
>
> debian-transmission 4096 марта 28 06:06 incomplete drwxrwxr-x 2 nat
>
> debian-transmission 4096 марта 28 06:06 torrents

And I tried changing USER in sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Problem is solved.

It was in mounting of my HDD. Automatically system gived me minimal rights. 
So I formatted my HDD to NTFS and added it to /etc/fstab

First find UUID of your diks

> ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

then edit fstab

> sudo nano /etc/fstab

add new line

> UUID={your uuid}  /mnt/nat ntfs-3g 0 0

reboot system and add new download rout to /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
That's all, No need in steps from previous post.